# Change from DOM manipulation to Angular binding for td Element to retrieve new details

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

So I have this tr Element where upon click of the edit button, the tdElement for the redirectUrl becomes editable. Obviously, I can use the id of the tdElement and change the contenteditable attr to true and use JQuery to retrieve the newly typed data.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in redirectsCtrl.tableData">
    <td style="text-align:left;" id="sourceUrl_{{$index + 1}}" >{{item.sourceUrl}}</td>
    <td style="text-align:left;" id="redirectUrl_{{$index + 1}}">{{item.redirectUrl}}</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;" role="button" id="editButton_{{$index + 1}}" ng-click="redirectsCtrl.onEditButtonClick(item, $event)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;" role="button" id="saveButton_{{$index + 1}}" ng-click="redirectsCtrl.onSaveButtonClick(item, $event)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;" role="button" ng-click="redirectsCtrl.onDeleteButtonClick(item)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></td>
</tr>
```

I want to be able to set the contenteditable attr to true/false and get the newly typed data from that td element (assuming contenteditable==true) upon clicking the saveButton using angular directives (NO DOM-based manipulation). I'm open to any suggestion and would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good place to start:

https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/ - Editable field directives

Answer (score 0):

you can try using ng-model='$parent.PropertyToWhichYouWantToGetNewValue'